# Magento 2 Create order even if product Qty is Zero

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, sales-order, sales-quote

I want to create an order programmatically where a product qty is zero. I am unable to do so at I get a message as

> {"0":"The requested qty is not available","1":"#1
> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor->addProduct(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000077f6b2d40000000016a081f7#,
> 1)

**Is there a way to create this types of orders?**

Comment: Hi any help regarding this?

Comment: Ideally there is no such scenario where the order qty is zero. Magento doesn't allow to do so. Even if you wanna do that you need to override the repositories where the validation logic is written. But could you elaborate why are you trying to do so ?